# I need a query for this select column_name from tbl1 where remarks = 'accepted' together with a union query with another table

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I've been researching and thinking a lot on how to make a query for my gridview data in asp.net where it will show the id and name with score.

Let's say I have this table_Info where it has columns `ID, NAME, REMARKS`
and other `table_score` where columns are `ID, SCORE`

I've already made this one:

```
SELECT table_Info.ID, table_Info.NAME, 
table_score.SCORE 
FROM table_Info
RIGHT JOIN  table_score ON table_Info.ID = table_score.ID
```

it works but the data of from table_Info that will show and be used should only be those of with the remarks of `ACCEPTED`

So it's like I need to combine the query above to this

```
SELECT * FROM table_Info WHERE REMARKS = 'ACCEPTED'
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: It seems like a one to one relation between the tables. If so you don't need a right join. You can use an inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your WHERE in the first query, like below:

```
SELECT  table_Info.ID
        ,table_Info.NAME
        ,table_score.SCORE 
FROM    table_Info
RIGHT
JOIN    table_score ON table_Info.ID = table_score.ID
WHERE   table_Info.REMARKS = 'ACCEPTED'
```

Comment: Ahm, I have another question. 
How can I make a button in gridview that will update the column for the score only?

Comment: It's a completely new question you're asking for -:) You'd rather write a new post specifying the langage used for with related tags.